# How can I list all of my steam games I've ever downloaded in my library?

Tags: steam

Some time ago I downloaded a bunch of steam games, that later I found out I couldn't play due to my shit graphics card. Now that I got a new one, I want to re download them, but they don't show up in my library, only some do. Also, I did I system restore to my pcs original settings and things. Is here any way I can list all of the games?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have your filter set wrong.  Try following these instructions:

> **Most of my games appear but some are missing**
>
> Sometimes Steam will appear to be functioning correctly, except
>   certain games will be missing from your list. If you are absolutely
>   sure that you are logged in to the correct Steam account, then the
>   issue is most likely that your filter is set incorrectly. Please log
>   in to your Steam account using the Steam client and ensure that all
>   games are visible by clicking View > All Games on the upper-left
>   corner of the Library > Games list.
>
> Another possibility is that some ports are being blocked by your
>   firewall and/or router. Since Steam cannot connect on all of the ports
>   it uses, it may run into a problem verifying one of your games. To see
>   the list of ports and to make sure that all of the ports for Steam are
>   open, please follow this guide.

From the Steam support [site](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5168-EUIA-6643)